# Cookie with a blank name - is this valid?

Tags: javascript, apache, http, cookies

I've noticed it's possible to set a strange cookie using the following code:

`document.cookie = 'foo;'`

This gets sent to the server without a name; e.g. `a=1; b=2; foo;`

Is this a valid kind of cookie? Is `foo` the name or the value of the cookie?

The reason I ask is this seems to cause errors in some of our webapps, and I'm wondering if it's a bug in their cookie parsing logic, or if this is actually a totally invalid cookie.

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-2.2

Answer (score 0):

foo would be the name of cookie. See the following example for creating a cookie:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Take a look here for a bit more info: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp